# How to install psycopg2 on Namecheap cPanel

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2, namecheap

I've been trying to get my Namecheap website up but I can't seem to get past psycopg2 requirement, which handles PostgreSQL for my flask code.

It can't install because I don't have the build requirements, one of which is libpq-dev, which seems to only be available on Linux. I'm trying to install it on my VM through a cPanel terminal.

Any different approaches I could take would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

This installs a pre-compiled binary that does not need the -dev libraries.

Comment: Yes, but this is a production environment, and the docs say to only use the binary for development. I'm managing the Binary for now until I can find a solution

Comment: Then you will need to install a dev stack.